# Do I need to wrap quotes around font family names in CSS?

Tags: css, font-family, quotation-marks

I remember hearing a long time ago that it was considered "best practice" to wrap quotes around font names that contain multiple words in the CSS font-family property, like this:

```
font-family: "Arial Narrow", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

For the heck of it, I tried removing the quotes from `"Arial Narrow"` and Safari and Firefox don't have any problem rendering it.

So, is there any logic to this rule of thumb, or is it just a myth? Was it an issue with older browsers that no longer applies to the current versions? I've been doing this for so long that I never stopped to think if it was actually necessary.

Comment: I think it's a good idea to quote every font family, less the generic ones.  It keeps things consistent.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The [CSS 2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-family-prop) tells us that:

> Font family names must either be given quoted as strings, or unquoted
>   as a sequence of one or more identifiers. This means most punctuation
>   characters and digits at the start of each token must be escaped in
>   unquoted font family names.

It goes on to say:

> If a sequence of identifiers is given as a font family name, the
>   computed value is the name converted to a string by joining all the
>   identifiers in the sequence by single spaces.
>
> To avoid mistakes in escaping, it is recommended to quote font family
>   names that contain white space, digits, or punctuation characters
>   other than hyphens:

So yes, there is a difference, but one that's unlikely to cause any problems. Personally, I have always quoted font names when they contain spaces. In a few (presumably very rare) cases, the quotes are absolutely required:

> Font family names that happen to be the same as a keyword value
>   ('inherit', 'serif', 'sans-serif', 'monospace', 'fantasy', and
>   'cursive') must be quoted to prevent confusion with the keywords with
>   the same names. The keywords 'initial' and 'default' are reserved for
>   future use and must also be quoted when used as font names.

Also note that punctuation such as / or ! within an identifier [may also need](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/unquoted-font-family) to be quoted or escaped.

Comment: `initial` and `default` are keywords too (they’re reserved for future use). See [_Unquoted font family names in CSS_](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/unquoted-font-family).

Answer (score 26):

According to the [CSS Fonts Module Level 3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#family-name-value) of October 2013, "*font family names other than generic families must either be given quoted as strings, or unquoted as a sequence of one or more identifiers*". **So you DO NOT need to enclose them in quotes.**

However, if you don't "*most punctuation characters and digits at the start of each token must be escaped*". **To avoid escaping mistakes, the W3C actually recommends to quote font family names containing white space, digits, punctuation or keyword values** (‘inherit’, ‘serif’, etc.).

The generic font family names (‘serif’, ‘sans-serif’, ‘cursive’, ‘fantasy’, and ‘monospace’) MUST NOT be quoted as they are actually keywords.

Answer (score 3):

If style is inline, like `<font style="font-family:Arial Narrow">some texte</font>`, it works.

But if the name of the police font contains some special characters, or starts with a number contains a quotes or others strange things (like "01 Digitall" or "a_CityNovaTitulB&WLt" or "Bailey'sCar"), you must use a special syntax with ***&quot;*** which can be applied to all kinds of stranges fonts names:

```
<font style="font-family:&quot;a_CityNovaTitulB&WLt&quot; , &quot;Bailey'sCar&quot;">some text</font>
```

In FireFox,the source will show the **&quot;** as this: **"**

without this trick, this:

```
<font style="font-family:a_CityNovaTitulB&WLt ,Bailey'sCar">some text</font>
```

doesn't automatically work in every browser.
It's useful for font name witch start by a number to, like "8 Pin".