# How to make a font gisha-regular?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am working from this wireframe: http://www.problemio.com/wireframe.pdf and I am supposed to make a gisha regular font, and I am googling for it, and it doesn't seem to be one of the standard fonts.

I tried doing something like this in css:

```
body 
{
    font-family: "Gisha-regular, Century Gothic,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif";
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 1em;
    background-color : white;
}
```

But it just gives me one of the other default fonts.

Any idea how I can get the gisha-regular to appear?

Thanks!

Comment: It's likely that there is no online licence for this font. Your designer should know better!

Comment: @Diodeus is there a font which looks close to this one? My designer is a bit green :)

Comment: Just a note that your font names shouldn't all be wrapped in a single set of quotes, but regardless, that font won't work out the box. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638775/do-i-need-to-wrap-quotes-around-font-family-names-in-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a standard font.

You have to make it a webfont, if so licensed.

Comment: how do I do that? Do I have to pay for it? Will it have trouble rendering in many browsers?

Comment: You have to find the foundry and license with them. Many modern browsers do support it.