# @font-face not working in my style.css

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have been searching on the web to find an answer to this question, but couldn't find one.
In my style.css I'm using @font-face to use a font (that I uploaded on the server of my webiste) on my website.
I did the right thing, I think so, but the font still won't show up on the website..

My code in style.css:

```
@font-face { font-family: Brandon Grotesque; src: url('BGREG.otf'); } 

@font-face { font-family: Brandon Grotesque; font-weight: bold; src: url('BGBOLD.otf');}
```

What's wrong? Or do I have to add some code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you set something `font-family: Brandon Grotesque`?

You just added your font to the "available" fonts. Didn't tell something to use it. Understand? Like, you have Arial, Comic Sans, Tahoma. But to use, you need to set.

```
body{
font-family: Brandon Grotesque;
}
```

[>more about](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/)

_

**Example:**

where

```
/
/ index.html
/ style
  | style.css
  | BGREG.otf
  | BGBOLD.otf
```

**/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>My title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<p class="something-bold">Bold</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**style/style.css**

```
@font-face {
font-family: Brandon Grotesque;
src: url('BGREG.otf'); 
}

@font-face {
font-family: Brandon Grotesque;
font-weight: bold; 
src: url('BGBOLD.otf');
}

body{
font-family: Brandon Grotesque;
}

.something-bold{
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Try (:

You can too load fonts from [Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts). Easily, by script import, by import on css, or JS.

Comment: Yes, I did, I already found the solution, my style.css file wasn't in the root folder, the font was. So that's why is didn't work.

Comment: Remember, if the answer helped you, mark it as solution :)

Comment: Oh, congrats. If you wanna add your css to a folder and font to another, look:

Just add the folder location before your font link in @font-face:
@font-face { font-family: Brandon Grotesque; src: url('`../fonts/BGREG.otf`'); }

per example

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to enclose your font name in quotes:

```
@font-face {font-family: "Brandon Grotesque";}

body{font-family: "Brandon Grotesque";}
```

[Do I need to wrap quotes around font family names in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638775/do-i-need-to-wrap-quotes-around-font-family-names-in-css)