# Why does my font stack ignore locally installed fonts? (chrome)

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, font-family

Not too sure if this has been asked before with specifics to *Locally Available* fonts.

I'm loading two font stacks on my local development site

```
// font stacks - http://cssfontstack.com/
"Arial", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
"Georgia", Cambria, Times New Roman, Times, serif;
```

The Arial font stack behaves as expected however the Georgia font stack skips Georgia and Cambria on Chrome. Firefox displays both exactly as expected. Both fonts exist on my local machine... Does anyone have any reasons why this would be happening?

Comment: Possibly related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638775/do-i-need-to-wrap-quotes-around-font-family-names-in-css

Comment: If Sass is generating the desired results, you're better off asking a pure CSS question than to muddy the waters with Sass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you see result of Issue 421305 @ Chromium http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=421305

scottmg@chromium.org says: "If DirectWrite fails to enumerate the system font collection (corrupt font, etc.), or we exceed 1750 fonts, we abort and load a very small set that does not include Verdana or Georgia. Obviously this is a hack. Shrikant has a patch out to fix this properly. In the interim, the only quick fixes are to reduce the number of fonts in %WINDOWS%\Fonts below 1750, or go to chrome://flags and disable DirectWrite."

The problem affects Chrome 38 and AFAIK last Opera with webkit core too... confirmed are issues with Georgia, Verdana, Tahoma, Calibri, Trebuchet and other locally hosted fonts.

It should be fixed in Chrome 39+

Comment: You're welcome, it seems to be fixed in last Chrome @ Windows build 38.0.2125.111 now...