# Font family "Arial black" parsing issue in chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am facing, the font-family issue in Chrome browser. while applying the font-family "arial black", the chrome parsing the double quotes with the string.
so it applies like below.

```
 style="font-family:"arial black";padding-left:10px;"
```

After saved, while reading the content, it is throwing the parsing issue.

Note: The font-family not parsed properly.

```
 style="font-family:"
```

Thanks,

Comment: so sounds like you need to deal with nested quotes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need to wrap quotes around font family names in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638775/do-i-need-to-wrap-quotes-around-font-family-names-in-css)

Answer (score 1):

try using a single quote
`style="font-family:'arial black'; padding:15px"`

Comment: By default Chrome browser apply the double qoutes."arial black", if the font have double words.

The problem only in Chrome browser. not in Firefox.

Comment: See Note 2 on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-family.asp)