# Font Helvetica Neue is converted to "Helvetica Neue" when assigning to CSSStyle​Declaration​.css​Text

Tags: css, stylesheet

Font Helvetica Neue is converted to "Helvetica Neue" when assigning to CSSStyle​Declaration​.css​Text

This works fine in IE and FF but not in chrome

## Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = myFunction();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

function myFunction() {
var body = document.body;
var style = body.style;
style.cssText = "font-size:small;font-family:Helvetica Neue"
  return style.cssText.toString();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Steps to reproduce the problem:
1. Save the above html code and open in Chrome browser
2. It displays : font-size: small; font-family: "Helvetica Neue";

What is the expected behavior?
It should display : font-size: small; font-family: Helvetica Neue;

What went wrong?
The Helvetica Neue is getting displayed in double quotes when assigned to .cssText.

Because of this, in our rich text editor source code mode, the "Helvetica Neue" is getting displayed "Helvetica Neue"

When assigned the value Helvetica Neue to .cssText, it should convert simply Helvetica Neue but not as "Helvetica Neue".

If there is no space in between Helvetica Neue, then it is properly converting. But we need space in between Helvetica Neue

Is there any way to get the font without quotes?

Comment: In JS you can just replace the quotes

Comment: I can replace ..but once we assign it back to style.cssText, it will display with qoutes.

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638775/do-i-need-to-wrap-quotes-around-font-family-names-in-css