# CSS font-family Which variant is correct?

Tags: css

Which variant is correct? Raleway or "Raleway"

`a) body {
         font-family: Raleway;
}`

```
b) body {
     font-family: "Raleway";
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need to wrap quotes around font family names in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638775/do-i-need-to-wrap-quotes-around-font-family-names-in-css)

Comment: @ItayGanor if you know a duplicate, why answering?

Comment: @TemaniAfif My mistake. deleted.