# font style is not changing in my html page

Tags: html, css

This is the code I followed:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Architects+Daughter&family=Palette+Mosaic&display=swap');

.container {
   font-family: Architects Daughter;
}

h3 {    
   color:brown ;
}
```

this is the result I got

[image]

Comment: where you'r importing this Url index file or any other place?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need to wrap quotes around font family names in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638775/do-i-need-to-wrap-quotes-around-font-family-names-in-css)

Answer (score 1):

`font-family: Architects Daughter` <-- Architects Daughter must be in quotes because it has a space in the name.

From [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family):

> `<family-name>`
> The name of a font family. For example, "Times" and
> "Helvetica" are font families. **Font family names containing whitespace
> should be quoted. For example: "Comic Sans MS"**.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Architects+Daughter&family=Palette+Mosaic&display=swap');

.container {
   font-family: "Architects Daughter";
}

h3 {    
   color:brown ;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="container">Login</h3>
```

Comment: @SHaripriya But, as you can see here, it does work. You must have other issues as well.